# How to delete hmtl tags using python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, ado

I am looking for a method to delete the records held in 'content' tag on my ADO wikipage.

I've checked the json content of what my url page holds:

```
def wiki_update(vm_list):
     pyautogui.hotkey('f5')
     pat = get_or_set_secret(kv_url, pat_secret_name, " ")
     authorization = base64.b64encode(f":{pat}".encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')
     basic_auth_value = f"Basic {authorization}"
     get_headers = {"Authorization": basic_auth_value}
    
     get_response = requests.get(wiki_url, verify=True, headers=get_headers)
     content = json.loads(get_response.text)
     print(content.content)
```

The output is:

```
{'path': '/MyWikiPage', 'order': 1, 'gitItemPath': '/Test%2DDebugVM%2DRemove%2DContent.md', 'subPages': [], 'url': 'https://dev.azure.com/xxx/123456789a6ba0154ffce/_apis/wiki/wikis/12345981-0649bdzsbf7aad/pages/%2FTest-DebugVM-Remove-Content', 'remoteUrl': 'https://dev.azure.com/xxx/123456789a6ba0154ffce/_apis/wiki/wikis/12345981-0649bdzsbf7aad?pagePath=%2FMyWikiPage', 'id': 14523, 'content': '\n|virtual machine name | ADO ticket | owner Email | creation date |\n|--|--|--|--|\n| my-12345-vm-0 | #12345 | hi.work@gmail.com | 29-01-2024 |'}
```

The specific tag I want to remove the items inside is 'content':

```
'content': '\n|virtual machine name | ADO ticket | owner Email | creation date |\n|--|--|--|--|\n| my-12345-vm-0 | #12345 | hi.work@gmail.com | 29-01-2024 |'
```

I do want to keep the headers, so the items I need help removing are:

```
my-12345-vm-0 | #12345 | hi.work@gmail.com | 29-01-2024 |
```

Here the the HTML output from the wikipage:

```
<script id="dataProviders" type="application/json">{"data":{".... ,"content":"|virtual machine name | ADO ticket | owner Email | creation date |\n|--|--|--|--|\n| my-12345-vm-0 | #12345 | hi.work@gmail.com | 29-01-2024 |"},
```

Comment: There's nothing HTML-related here?

Comment: It might be a good idea to have the *exact* data you want to remove in the original.

Comment: Would be helpful to provide the exact HTML structure OP is working with.

Comment: What you have seems to be [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (the `.md` extension also suggests that), see table syntax for example on [github](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/organizing-information-with-tables). That's why a HTML parser is not very helpful here. Try something like https://www.google.com/search?q=python+parse+markdown+table instead.